# Wordpress fails to generate .htaccess file

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

Wordpress does not have the permission to generate .htaccess or config files.
I just setup a LAMP server with the apt-get install lamp-server^ command on ubuntu.

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in Apache logs? How about `/var/log/messages`, perhaps an [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) profile for Apache is preventing WordPress from scribbling all over your content.

Comment: This is what it says:

[Mon Feb 21 01:42:07 2011] [crit] [client 24.11.8.22] (13)Permission denied: /home/domain.com/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://domain.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: I changed it because I don't want my actual domain showing up on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /home/domain.com should have owner to be www-data and group www-data

Access rights for that folder must be `755 (rwxr-xr-x)`

basically, just type these two :

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/domain.com
sudo chmod 755 /home/domain.com
```

I would recommend to review access rights for the various folders of your installation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a big deal, you can manually create the .htaccess file yourself, wordpress will give you the code that you need to copy paste if it can't create the file itself.

With the config file (guessing you mean wp-config(-sample).php), you can edit those values manually, you don't need to use the installer for that.

Have a read through this page and double check you have all the correct file/folder permissions for your wordpress installation